# Student Kiosk software for Windows that can limit applications & websites

Tags: windows, web-browser, educational, desktop-environment, kiosk

I am interested in finding desktop replacement software that allows a limited set of applications and websites for an educational setting.

This software must be compatible with Windows 7.

Comment: Does the price matter?

Comment: @Tom, price always matters. Why?

Comment: We're not particularly price sensitive, though.

Answer (score -1):

KioWare or KioskSimple are good Win kiosk software. I have worked with both. My company sells payment peripherals that work with either of these. I have known the folks at KioWare for many years and the folks at KioskSimple for a couple now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing – but can you please [edit] your answer and include links (where to find the products), plus describe how they meet the OPs requirements (describe the matching features)? Thanks!